# url optimization in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins

Hello I want to create seo optimize url in rails.Same like done in stackoverflow.
Right now this is my url

```
http://localhost:3000/questions/56
```

I want to make it something like this:-

```
http://localhost:3000/questions/56/this-is-my-optimized-url
```

i am using restful approach.
is there any plug-in available for this.

Comment: Have a look here:
[http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_permalinks___slugs.html](http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_permalinks___slugs.html)

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked for a plugin, but a dead simple approach is just to override the to_param method in your model. You can just append the seo name to the id.

For example:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  #has attribute name.

  def to_param
    "#{id}-#{name.parameterize}"
  end
end
```

The path/url helpers will then generate a path like so:

```
show_question_path(@question)
>> /questions/12345-my-question-name
```

You do not need to do anything to your routes.

Your controller will remain Question.find(params[:id]) as the param will have to_i called on it, which will strip off the name and just return the id.

Comment: The _url and _path methods provided by the restful routes you define call to_param on the object passed in.

So in this instance show_question_path(@question) is calling @question.to_param to get the id of the object and useing that to generate the route.

The ActiveRecord::find will take the id at that point (12-example) and run to_i on it. the String::to_i function will convert any numeric characters in the beginning of a string to an integer, and ignore the rest.

Thank explain things more fully?

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend looking into the [`friendly_id`](http://github.com/norman/friendly_id) plugin. The [FriendlyId Guide](http://norman.github.com/friendly_id/file.Guide.html) is a great place to start.  I have been using this in production for a number of months and it works great.

Using the [cached slugs](http://norman.github.com/friendly_id/file.Guide.html#caching_the_friendlyid_slug_for_better_performance) feature makes this a very scalable solution. Additionally I'd recommend using it combination with [`stringex`](http://norman.github.com/friendly_id/file.Guide.html#converting_nonwestern_characters_to_ascii_with_stringex) if you deal with non-ASCII characters.